# Validation Rule checking if Quote is synced when Opp is set to Closed won

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation-rule

I made a validation rule which verifies that a Quote was synced before the Opportunity can be set to closed won.

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "08 - Closed Won"), 
ISBLANK(  SyncedQuote.Id )
)
```

No problems so far. But now I want to add two more permissions:
There should be no Error Message
when the Opportunity Name contains " 3rd Level Support"
OR
when Quote Name contains "Renewal" or "prolongation"

Is this even possible? Makes no logical sense to me to check if a Quote contains a some words when I'm initially checking if its even existing, but I think I'm overlooking something..

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "08 - Closed Won"), 
ISBLANK(  SyncedQuote.Id ),
NOT(CONTAINS(SyncedQuote.Name, 'Renewal') ),
NOT(CONTAINS(SyncedQuote.Name, 'prolongation') ),
NOT(CONTAINS( Name , '3rd Level Support'))
)
```